# Complex number argument $[0,2\pi]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Which is the right interval of angles to choose in a exercise involving complex numbers, $[0,2\pi]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$? The problem is that sometimes results are different, I'll make an example:

Calculate $(\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{1-i\sqrt3})^{{333}}$

I used the exponential forms and I chose $-\frac{\pi}{3}$ as the argument of $1-i\sqrt3$
 $(\frac{2 e^i\frac{\pi}{3}}{2 e^i(-\frac{\pi}{3})})^{{333}}= (e^i\frac{2\pi}{3})^{{333}} =(e^{i222\pi})=1$

Whereas if I choose $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ i get
 $(\frac{2 e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}}{2 e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}})^{{333}}= (e^{i(-\frac{\pi}{3})})^{{333}} =(e^{i(-111\pi)})=-1$

Is there any mistake in what I did? In general which angle range should one choose?

Comment: $5\pi/3$, not $2\pi/3$.

Comment: For integer powers, the argument does not matter. (Re the title, neither $[0,2\pi]$ nor $[-\pi,\pi]$ is a suitable interval for the argument. Common choices are $[0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi]$.)

Comment: Thanks I made a stupid mistake! And in general (not integer powes) results do not depend on the choice of the interval right?

Comment: For non integer powers, the result very much depends on the choice of the argument. Which is why there is no canonical definition of the function $z\mapsto z^a$ on $\mathbb C$ when $a$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

for the numerator it is correct what you have done.
However, for the denominator the right angle is $$-\pi/3\ or\ 5\pi/3$$
as the point is located in the fourth quarter of the cartesian coordinates ( real part is positive and imaginary part is negative)